# Set require validation , asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, require

I have a form with two button and text-boxes,I want to have validation for my text-boxes when I click on button-1 NOT for when I click on Button-2,

```
         <td >
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ErrorMessage="User ID is required."> *
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">     </asp:TextBox>
```

this method works for all of my button :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in both textboxes use group/groupname property(don't remember exact name) eg. grope=grope1

use this "grope1" name in grope property of button1 and not in button2's grope property.